# concatenate column name and column values

Tags: r, data.table

i have the following

```
library(data.table)

anid <- c(1,2,3,4)
agroup <- c("m", "m", "f", "f")
anothergroup <- c("a","c", NA, "c")
avalue <- c(11,  6, 17, 3)
mygoal <- c("agroup:m_anothergroup:a","agroup:m_anothergroup:c","agroup:f_anothergroup:NA","agroup:f_anothergroup:c")
```

unfortunately i missed this line in my example

```
dt <- data.table(anid, agroup, anothergroup, avalue)
```

Basically I want to create the values of the column mygoal using a function, but unfortunately im stuck. I want to create the column mygoal using something similar like this

```
dt[, mygoal:= lapply(...)]
```

The number of columns that go into the function can vary, but nevertheless I know them but it has to be possible to provide the columns to the function as character vector. In the above example the columns "agroup" and "anothergroup" are used to create values for the column "mygoal".

Once again, any hint is appreciated

Tom

Comment: Why do you load `data.table`? Your problem description seems to be missing some details.

Comment: I load data.table because I missed this line in my example

Comment: @Roland I edited my question, sorry for the mess

Comment: @David Arenburg, thanks a lot for making my question more readable. I will try harder that is not necessary with my next question :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cols <- c("agroup", "anothergroup")
DT[, mygoal := do.call(paste, 
                       c(lapply(cols, function(x) paste(x, get(x), sep=":")),              
                         sep="_"))]
#   anid agroup anothergroup avalue                   mygoal
#1:    1      m            a     11  agroup:m_anothergroup:a
#2:    2      m            c      6  agroup:m_anothergroup:c
#3:    3      f           NA     17 agroup:f_anothergroup:NA
#4:    4      f            c      3  agroup:f_anothergroup:c
```

Comment: I just wanted to say - thanks! it saved me a lot of time, and this is an essential thing in my current working. I need it to somehow store a path of my data :-)

Comment: Is there a way to remove anothergroup:NA since that value is NA? so that the #3 mygoal is "agroup:f" instead of "agroup:f_anothergroup:NA"

Comment: Easiest would be to subset the data.table.